Blinking flowdocument when adding elements on Binding textblock
I created a flowdocment with 2 pages using  to create the second page.
ive binded elements like name and it seemed to work until i added the second page, and then i noted that, each time i modify the binded textblock  the second page blinks
Can somebody help to know what to do please?
This is a piece of code:
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    _printWorker = new PrintWorker();
    InitializeDataContext();


    // Génère et associe le FlowDocument.
    var flowDataDoc = _printWorker.GenerateFlowDocument();
  
    if (flowDataDoc == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to generate FlowDocument.");
    }

    flowDataDoc.DataContext = this.DataContext;
    DocumentViewer.Document = flowDataDoc;
}

I've tried to delete all elements on the second page, but the blinking continues.
